# Specifying level 2 style for a tree in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

The idea is to produce the org charts automatically by application code reading a database and calculating the node counts and sizes based on the names of teammates and their hierarchy.

After reading the PGF manual pp. 319-220, I devised the below MWE in order to draw a sample static org chart:

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape,ansibpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    left=2em,
    right=2em,
    top=2em,
    bottom=2em,
}

\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black, thin, minimum height=3em]

\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    supervisor/.style={%
        text centered, text width=12em,
        text=black
    },
    teammate/.style={%
        text centered, text width=12em,
        text=black
    },
    subordinate/.style={%
        grow=down,
        xshift=-3.2em, % Horizontal position of the child node
        text centered, text width=12em,
        edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.205) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}
    },
    level1/.style ={level distance=4em,anchor=west},
    level2/.style ={level distance=8em,anchor=west},
    level3/.style ={level distance=12em,anchor=west},
    level4/.style ={level distance=16em,anchor=west},
    level 1/.style={edge from parent fork down,sibling distance=14em,level distance=5em}
%   level 2/.style={edge from parent fork down,sibling distance=28em,level distance=5em}
]
    \node[anchor=south,supervisor](super){Supervisor\\Supervisory position\\Location}[]
    child{node [teammate] {Teammate6\\Position4\\Location4}
        child{node [teammate] {Teammate61\\Position4\\Location4}
            child[subordinate,level1] {node {Subordinate161}}
            child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate261}}}
        child{node [teammate] {Teammate62\\Position4\\Location4}
            child[subordinate,level1] {node {Subordinate162}}
            child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate262}}}  
        child{node [teammate] {Teammate62\\Position4\\Location4}
            child[subordinate,level1] {node {Subordinate162}}
            child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate262}}}  
    }
    child{node [teammate] {Teammate7\\Position5\\Location5}
        child{node [teammate] {Teammate7\\Position5\\Location5}
            child[subordinate,level1] {node {First\\Subordinate}}
            child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate2}}
            child[subordinate,level3] {node {Third\\Teammate}}
            child[subordinate,level4] {node {Longtext-\\teammate}}}
        child{node [teammate] {Teammate7\\Position5\\Location5}
            child[subordinate,level1] {node {First\\Subordinate}}
            child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate2}}
            child[subordinate,level3] {node {Third\\Teammate}}
            child[subordinate,level4] {node {Longtext-\\teammate}}}
    };

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output is (quite understandably) garbled:

[image]

I thought that uncommenting the `level 2` line would fix that, but it made the matters even worse:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a missing comma between `level 1/.style={...}` and `level 2/.style={...}` and you have to increase the sibling distance in `level 1`and to decrease in `level 2`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape,ansibpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2em]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black, thin, minimum height=3em]

\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    supervisor/.style={%
        text centered, text width=12em,
        text=black
    },
    teammate/.style={%
        text centered, text width=12em,
        text=black
    },
    subordinate/.style={%
        grow=down,
        xshift=-3.2em, % Horizontal position of the child node
        text centered, text width=12em,
        edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.205) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}
    },
    level1/.style ={level distance=4em,anchor=west},
    level2/.style ={level distance=8em,anchor=west},
    level3/.style ={level distance=12em,anchor=west},
    level4/.style ={level distance=16em,anchor=west},
    level 1/.style={edge from parent fork down,sibling distance=45em,level distance=5em},
    level 2/.style={edge from parent fork down,sibling distance=18em}
]
    \node[anchor=south,supervisor](super){Supervisor\\Supervisory position\\Location}[]
    child{node [teammate] {Teammate6\\Position4\\Location4}
        child{node [teammate] {Teammate61\\Position4\\Location4}
            child[subordinate,level1] {node {Subordinate161}}
            child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate261}}}
        child{node [teammate] {Teammate62\\Position4\\Location4}
            child[subordinate,level1] {node {Subordinate162}}
            child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate262}}}  
        child{node [teammate] {Teammate62\\Position4\\Location4}
            child[subordinate,level1] {node {Subordinate162}}
            child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate262}}}  
    }
    child{node [teammate] {Teammate7\\Position5\\Location5}
        child{node [teammate] {Teammate7\\Position5\\Location5}
            child[subordinate,level1] {node {First\\Subordinate}}
            child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate2}}
            child[subordinate,level3] {node {Third\\Teammate}}
            child[subordinate,level4] {node {Longtext-\\teammate}}}
        child{node [teammate] {Teammate7\\Position5\\Location5}
            child[subordinate,level1] {node {First\\Subordinate}}
            child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate2}}
            child[subordinate,level3] {node {Third\\Teammate}}
            child[subordinate,level4] {node {Longtext-\\teammate}}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, a syntax error that did not prevent compilation... Good eye! Thx